# I can't connect to internet : network manager is disabled

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, iwlwifi

Everything began when I was trying to use aircrack-ng suite on my ubuntu 12.04.

I found on aircrack-ng website (http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=b43) that using a Broadcom driver and a wl driver at the same time, it will choose the wl driver and aircrack-ng is incompatible with wl driver.

I choosed to desactivate it through the modprobe blacklist set in : '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf' adding the line blacklist wl (where it was written b43XX before) and it blacklisted it.

here is the problem : after a reboot, impossible to connect to internet, I restored the blacklist file as it was before and rebooted. IMPOSSIBLE TO CONNECT TO INTERNET NEITHER.

Afortunately I have an USB TP-LINK anten, and could reactivate Broadcom driver (it was disabled too from additional drivers settings) and when I rebooted again, the b43 driver was again desactivated and I should use my USB anten to connect to internet to download and install BCM driver again... what a story. In fact it is installed but disabled. (because of the wl driver disabled I guess)

What can I do to reactivate wl driver ? Any idea ?

I add descriptions of what could help :

```
lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

    nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            atl1c
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        1C:75:08:4C:2C:34

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

There it should appear eth1 which is the name of my wireless card (yes it's weird but that's true)

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
wl                   2906597  0 
lib80211               14040  1 wl
iwlwifi               362337  0 
mac80211              436493  3 iwlwifi,ath9k_htc,b43
cfg80211              178877  6 wl,iwlwifi,ath9k_htc,ath,b43,mac80211


    NetworkManager.state *****


[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true


***** NetworkManager.conf *****


[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq


[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

---

```
dmesg | grep b43

[   29.990559] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4313 WLAN found (core revision 24)
[   29.991461] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 10, Type 8, Revision 1)
[   29.991489] b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -95
[ 3478.268637] b43-phy2: Broadcom 4313 WLAN found (core revision 24)
[ 3478.268812] b43-phy2 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 10, Type 8, Revision 1)
[ 3478.268837] b43: probe of bcma0:0 failed with error -95
```

something else I could add to help ?

Thanks by advance

EDIT : Resolved it this way :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

But I need to run the two last commands each time I will start my computer. How to create a script to run it at boot? Or where shall I add it (a configuration file?) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem about the need to run modprobe at every boot.
If my memory is good it was a problem with blacklisting

I think you should try to blacklist b43 and ssb by uncommenting the following lines:

```
# blacklist bcm43xx
# blacklist b43
```

since it looks like you remove them before before using wl to finally make it work.

Comment: I only removed everything talking about wl or b43 or b43xx from blacklist and it worked evrerything fine :)